# Why does audio sound different in waveform v. multitrack?

Tags: adobe-audition

I've been editing in Audition, and I can't figure out why my audio sounds different in waveform than it does in multitrack. It looks/sounds fine in Waveform, but it's super loud/constantly going into the red in multitrack. I can't figure out why. The dB is set at 0 in the multitrack, and the only effect in the multitrack is a graphic equalizer (when I turn that off, it doesn't make a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, I can think of only one thing. You said the level is at 0 dB on the track, and you mean the one on the left side where I have +0 in my screenshot below, correct?

But there is a second place to set a level, circled red in my screenshot. When I increase it, only the multitrack playback is affected, not waveform. Click on the icon and hold it, then move your mouse to the left to decrease it. If it's at 0 dB the icon looks a bit different and there is no text. If that's the case my answer won't help you and it's something else.

[image: multitrack]

Comment: I think that was it — it was indeed set higher in the circled area. Do you know how to change the levels for all the clips in the track at once by chance? Or should I change them one by one?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I don't know a way to change it for all tracks at once.